# How to parse JSON web server reponse when HTTP code is an error?

Tags: jquery

### The setup

In a web application I 'm maintaining there are lots of AJAX calls to submit forms that go like this:

```
jQuery.post($form.attr("action"), $form.serialize())
    .always(commonProcessing)
    .done(function() {
        // the post succeeded, do something specific (e.g. close a dialog)
    });
```

The `commonProcessing` function looks for "well known" parts in the JSON response and takes appropriate action (the response may also include request-specific information). It reads something like this:

```
function commonProcessing(result, outcome) {
    switch (outcome) {
        case "success":
            if (result.notify) {
                // show a growl-style notification
            }
            else if (...) ;
            break;
        case "error":
            // show a generic "unexpected error" notification
            break;
    }
}
```

### The problem

In many cases I 'd prefer to return an HTTP error code -- say 400 for a submitted form that has invalid data -- because, in addition to this being the natural order of things, it allows me to conveniently put the "successful request" code in a `.done` handler (if a 200 OK were returned instead then the content would be always parsed, but the `.done` handler would need to try and find out if this is an "error" or a "really OK" response). At the same time I want to respond to the request with specific information when an error occurs (for example the `notify` object can contain an error message that explains exactly what was wrong with the request).

The problem is that when an HTTP error code is returned, jQuery does not attempt to parse the response content, in which case the `result` argument is a jqXHR object instead of the typical parsed JSON.

Is there an elegant way of saying "I know that there was an error, but I also want you to parse the response content"? I could of course do `$.parseJSON(result.responseText)` since we 're talking about JSON, but that feels clumsy because it sidesteps all the nice [jQuery code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L798) that sniffs the content type and does the parsing.

Comment: Is this for any error, or specifically `5xx`?

Comment: Also, what is the actual error you get (in the error condition handler that is fired).

Answer (score 2):

What about using a try/catch block of code?

```
try{ 
     var response = $.parseJSON(response) etc 
}
catch(error){ 
     console.log(error) //error handling here
}
```

That is what I use to account for the instances where the response is not in JSON format as expected but an error code of some sort. Apologies in advance if I have misunderstood the question!

Comment: This is in fact about what I 'm doing right now as a best practical approach. But ideally I 'd want to leverage existing jQuery functionality to automatically parse the response into an appropriate format, be it JSON or anything else that jQuery understands.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can modify the jqXHR object to behave like that. Looking through the API ([here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)) the closest thing that occurs to me that might solve your issue is the `overrideMimeType()` method. Something like:

```
beforeSend: function(xhr){
    xhr.overrideMimeType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
}
```

If you're looking to take control in a more fine-grained manner, why not implement the AJAX call manually and return the object you wish, in the format you need it?

Comment: The MIME type is correctly sent by the server. The problem is that jQuery sees the HTTP 400 code *and chooses not to touch the content* (it simply makes it available as a string).

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean, though it confuses me that you're still expecting a fully formed response when an error occurs... ie. if you get a 404, what sort of response are you expecting to parse?
Fine grain your messages on HTTP status codes with the `statusCode` map.

Comment: Obviously we are not talking specifically about a 404.

Comment: Or a 400, or 500. jQuery's jqXHR is a superset of the original XHR. If you want the response parsed to JSON you won't have much of a choice but to do it manually, and wherever you do it you'll have to call JSON.parse, or an equivalent, eventually. Take a look at the [XHR spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-responsetext-attribute) to get a better idea of how the overriding is handled, if the implementation doesn't suit you.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily manage callbacks with:

```
$.ajax({
  url: $form.attr("action"),
  type: 'POST',
  data: $form.serialize(),
  complete: function(response) {},
  success: function(response) {},
  error: function(response) {}
});
```

Comment: I 'm not sure what you are saying here. I am already using the `complete` and `success` callbacks (albeit by their other names). The issue is that for `complete`, if the HTTP code is an error then `response` is not the parsed content as I would like it to be.

Comment: I think I misunderstood then :). Did you try to use `dataType: json`?

Comment: The problem is not a wrong or missing `Content-Type` value. It's that jQuery as written does not attempt to touch the content *at all* if the HTTP status code is a 4xx or 5xx.

Comment: So result.responseText is type of string for you? Can you post what the string looks like?

Comment: It's a string for anyone: response**Text**. And it's also a perfectly good JSON string. Please understand that my issue is completely unrelated to basic "cannot get correct response" problems.

Comment: I think there is no options to avoid `$.parseJSON` if you want to handle the error. However there is an option to return status code 200 with parameter that you would recognize as an error and it would give you an object from the response but I think it's better to parse the json

Answer (score -1):

My way of trying to maintain control over error response body is that I have written my php to catch most of the things that could go wrong and still return a valid json object, and inside of my JS success callback, I handle that object in there.

```
success: function( response ) {
    if(response) {

    } else {

    }
},
error: function( xhr ) {
    //everything worse gets sent here
}
```

From then, any really fundamental error that causes an ugly error code gets handled by the error callback.

Comment: I do that as well. The problem is that I want to return an HTTP error code along with the JSON, and that code causes the `error` handler to execute instead. It is possible to grab the JSON and parse it inside the error handler, but it's not convenient.

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, I can't see why that would ever work. basically if you were to load a page in your browser that failed immediately with some error code, where would the message be? in the header? if so, i guess my next question is, can you achieve this with a HEAD request? if not, then you should assume it cannot be done with a GET or POST

Comment: It would be in the response body as always, which is perfectly valid if not very common. The HTTP response code is independent of the content. For example, try `curl -i http://www.google.com/letsgeta404`. The server returns HTML content along with a 404 error code.

Comment: Oh nice I never knew about this google "letsgeta404" url! OK i see your point

Comment: There's nothing special about that URL, I just made it up ;-)

Comment: Damn you... lol i was going to use that at work for testing today. nevermind

Comment: Eh... it *does work*. Because Google does give a 404 along with HTML. Because the page does not exist. Because I made it up.